# how to create a new raster from one field of a raster with several fields in a RAT

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, fields-attributes, raster-attribute-table

I have a raster with an attribute table containing many fields.  I want to create a new raster from one field using ArcGIS 10.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Lookup](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000sn000000) tool/function. It's the poor substitute for the old [dot notation](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/47540-Lookup-function-in-v10.0-Map-Algebra-implementing-dot-notation-in-v10.0) syntax that ESRI products used to support for many many years...